# How to use the LotusScript to delete the Excel file after saving changes to it?

Tags: excel, com, lotusscript

I'm currently working on automating the compilation of an excel document that my company normally do manually. Essentially what I'm doing to give an overview is the following:

Taking a file from a document - it is an Embedded Rich Text Item - `ExtractFile()`'ing to the local disc, editing it as needed, using `SaveAs` to save the updated into the same directory. Sending out the file with the MIME. All of this works fine - and this is where my problem lies:

I am left with two files sitting in the specified directory. The last thing that I need the agent to do is to the delete this files. I had originally tried the `Kill` command followed by the specified directory. This had given me an OLE Automation Object Error; due to this I had gone and looked for new ways to attempt to delete a file to see if it would also give me the error. So I attempted the following:

```
Call createObject("scripting.filesystemobject").deletefile(filePath, True)
```

This had also given me the same error. I have tried a few other things, as well. Such as:

- Calling the `xlApp.Quit()` method on both of the excel files, no luck.
- Calling the `ReleaseComObject()`
- Throwing in a `Sleep(3)` to see if it would help me - found this on other forums

If you have any ideas to attempt to try to get this to work without an error that would be incredibly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the `Workbook.SaveAs` method, use [`Workbook.Close`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838613%28v=office.15%29.aspx) method to save you changes. After calling this method, the file is closed and it can be easily deleted. To delete file, use the standard LotusScript [`Kill`](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.main.doc/LSAZ_KILL_STATEMENT.html) statement.
Here is example:

```vb
'Get the document here

Set rtItem = doc.GetFirstItem(excelFileItem$)
Set obj = rtItem.EmbeddedObjects(0)

tempDir$ = Environ("Temp") & "\"

'These file names is just for example. Use your owns.
fileName$ = tempDir$ & obj.Source
saveAsFileName$ = tempDir$ & "New " & obj.Source

Call obj.ExtractFile(fileName$)

Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName$)

'Update excel here.

xlBook.Close True, saveAsFileName$, False'Save the file where you need to.
xlApp.Quit

'Send mail here.

Kill fileName$
Kill saveAsFileName$
```

If you send only one file and delete both files, then there is no need to save the changes to another file. You can save changes to the same file.